# BAT file for "User Info" with parameter from command prompt

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to run the script with parameter from cmd and without any further interaction, receive the output.

For example:
"netuser.bat JOHN"

Result:
Net user information for "John"

What I got at the moment:

```
goto :main

:main
set /p user=%1
net user %username% /domain

goto :eof
```

If I run the script as is,I will get:

C:\Users\John>netuser.bat John

John

*Output of net user command*

It asks me to confirm the parameter, in this case: "John" with return key. I'd like to skip that part, so the scripts executes after using "netuser.bat John" and doesn't ask for further confirmation.

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window and enter, `set /?`, you'd learn how to use the command. `/P` is for prompting and you don't want to be prompted, so remove that option: `Set "user=%~1"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, should have done more diligence on my side.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by *@Compo* in a comment, you should just `set "user=%~1"` and not use `set /p` which waits for user to press enter.

That being said, you can replace the above all with:

```
<nul set /p=|net user "%~1" /domain
```

It redirects input from nul and runs the command all in one go

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @lit because `set /p=|` on its own will still wait for user input... anyway, not sure what the purpose was that OP required `/P` so just made a one liner from his code.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - I understand using `<nul` to satiate `set /p`. I am wondering why `net use "$~1" /domain` is not all that is needed?

Comment: @lit Again, I am not understanding the reason why OP used `set /p` and it was never clarified `:)`